# How do i sample an audio file say .wav , in an 8 bit 8khz parameter

Tags: audio, lua, sampling

i am not that big on programming and i need to sample an audio file that is recorded via a mobile, i understand that the mobile device records the voice, and there are sample rates and each sample has a 8bit or 16 bit sample size. i need 8 bit sample size in 8khz. the programming environment is lua but that doesnt matter really the basic deal is sampling. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Actually your programming environment, in particular the one on your mobile phone, does matter a lot. Probably it makes more sense using a library rather than processing the waves "manually". But if you want to go low-level, go to Wikipedia as a start point for the wave format. Some basic understanding of FFT might come handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either set your recording parameters at the time that you record the sound sample to 8 bits @ 8 kHz, or, if you can't, or don't have any control over the actual recording process, then you will need to *resample* the original recording to get it into the format that you need. You can do this off-line with a tool such as [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/SoX/Resampling), or you can write code that does this on-the-fly. If you give more detail in your question then I can add more specific detail in my answer.

Comment: Thanks mate, the details are that yes i know i can resample it but i need the wave form in an array and divide the normally 2000 3000 indexes in 10-12 segments and then process the information hence making the audio matching much faster and enhanced, the resampling does'nt give me that does it? i actually dont know that. Also the programming environment is Corona SDK which as of their API and my understanding only lets you specify the sample rate not the waveform or sample bit size. Any cross-platform mobile development environment gives me that if it can't be done on this?

Comment: @Mohammad: the whole *point* of resampling is to get your waveform to the required sample rate and bit depth, i.e. 8 bits @ 8 kHz, from whatever sample rate and bit depth you are starting out with.

Comment: I get that but i need the waveform in the array and i from what i've read, (THE WHOLE FRIGGIN API) I can't do that, obviously if i need to match audio samples i cant use the whole audio file everytime, so how else do i do it if i cant get the waveform, any suggestions? might i add you're helpful as hell and it is much appreciated

Comment: You probably need to ask a new question, since your original question was about getting the audio into the right format (8 bits @ 8 kHz) but now you seem to be asking about how to divide a file or stream of audio into chunks for some kind of matching (I'm guessing you're trying to do something like Shazam ?).

Comment: Oh no not like shazam, somewhat different but, thanks a bunch, i'll post another question

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about lua, but as suggested by Paul R, you can always post-process your audio files using SoX or ffmpeg. On linux, just install ffmpeg :

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Then :

```
ffmpeg -i trenet.wav -ar 8000 trenet-8k.wav
```

This resamples your audio at 8000 Hz. I did not find how to deal with the bits/sample parameter but you can always tune the bitrate. For documentation :

```
man ffmpeg
```